# "Multiple" vs. "additional"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

When you are adding or inserting additional people to a list, what is the correct word to use, *multiple* or *additional*?  Example:

> - Multiple escorts can be added using the Add New Escort tab.
> - Additional escorts may be added using the Add New Escort tab.

Comment: Hm, is this for . . . an escort service? :)

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have different meanings for me.
The first one says ‘you can add one or more at the same time’ while my understanding of the second one is ‘if there is an existing one, you still can add some more’.

So the first one does not say anything about whether escorts can be added in several steps, like two in the first and three in the second step,
while the second one says nothing about how many could be added in each step.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the ability exists to add more than one at a time, I would go with "Additional escorts"